Posting in my Facebook feed with GraphAPI not working
I want to post something in my FB feed wall (not any Page) using graph API.
The Permissions:
pages_show_list
instagram_content_publish
pages_read_engagement
pages_read_user_content
pages_manage_posts
pages_manage_engagement

User or Page: User Token. Thus I generated the Access Token.
Next I am using the curl:
curl -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/me/feed" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{
           "message": "some msg",
           "link": "some link to an image",
           "published": "true",
           "access_token": "the access token I got as mentioned above"

And I am getting this error:
 }'
{"error":{"message":"(#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \\\n          either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both pages_read_engagement \\\n          and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, \\\n          requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with \\\n          sufficient administrative permission","type":"OAuthException","code":200,"fbtrace_id":"AT-wsNX19z1oFPFxq0tbLZF"}}%  

What I do not understand about the error message is that I am trying not to post in any group/page, but just my FB feed wall.
But later, I decided to create a Page, and try posting there. The code I used to get the Page is:
url -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/me/accounts?access_token=theaccesstoken
>>>
[{"access_token":"some access token, I am not sure what this is","category":"Property","category_list":[{"id":"198327773511962","name":"Property"}],"name":"MyTest","id":"394143863782471","tasks":["ADVERTISE","ANALYZE","CREATE_CONTENT","MESSAGING","MODERATE","MANAGE"]}],"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"QVFIUkVZASmx4RXhWemFZAX19pOGZALaTZAfMVJlTUtpaXZALMVlucnZAhVnc4WktZAV1hYUm1JTjE4NW5EOUdCYjRoTGRnLU1xSl9VZAi1qZAy1wbVJ6UWJ1cENHaXRR","after":"QVFIUkVZASmx4RXhWemFZAX19pOGZALaTZAfMVJlTUtpaXZALMVlucnZAhVnc4WktZAV1hYUm1JTjE4NW5EOUdCYjRoTGRnLU1xSl9VZAi1qZAy1wbVJ6UWJ1cENHaXRR"}}}

I assume that 394143863782471 is the page_id as yes the name of my page is MyTest.
Then I used from here:
curl -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/394143863782471/photos" \
     -F "source=@/path to my image" \
     -F "caption=some caption" \
     -F "access_token=the access token of the app

>>>
{"error":{"message":"(#200) The permission(s) publish_actions are not available. It has been deprecated. If you want to provide a way for your app users to share content to Facebook, we encourage you to use our Sharing products instead.","type":"OAuthException","code":200,"fbtrace_id":"AWHagdudbcBgpKNO6yPYM73"}}%   

I cannot understand what this error means. Can someone help?
